# Crystal Report does not keep dataset toghether

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, dataset

I have a template report in which I giving data to dataset and importing 3 subreports. My dataset has a one datatable with 3 records. When I set that vi c# code and import my 3 subreports, I am getting this situation:

[image]

So, it goes like this: One record (James Bond) and then 3 subreports... Then the second record (Rocky Balboa) and then 3 subreports.

I need to have 3 records (James Bond, Rocky Balboa and Keyser Soze) and then once 3 imported subreports (each color represents a subreport). I want it like this:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Design mode:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you want here .. Do you want your 3 ( or X ) records and after this records your 3 subreports ? Could you please post your crystalreport design ?

Comment: @Furtiro I made an edit with the image what I want.

Comment: Thanks, could you please post your crystal report in design mode ? ( with your actual sections )

Comment: OK, done. @Furtiro

Comment: Hum, i needed this screenshoot to see your actual sections .. In your screen i can't see anything ^^'

Comment: 5 default sections. Report Header which is suppressed, Page Header with the labels, one Detail section and Report and Page Footers. It is default. @Furtiro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122497/discussion-between-furtiro-and-sid-broklyn).

Comment: looks like you have imported sub reports in detail section... for your requirement you need to place the sub reports in footer sections (Group or Report).. Also in your image I can't see any sub reports.

Comment: ok in that case in which section have you added your sub reports?

Comment: @Siva Post you answer separated and I will flag it as correct and highlight it, because I put my reports in Report Footer and everything is OK.

Comment: @SidBroklyn Added as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Details will repeat for every record hence when you place the sub reports in details your sub reports are repeated for every record.. if you need to get only once then for your case place it in footers (`Group or Report`) as per your requirement and you will get correct result.